# How to use GemBox.Spreadsheet in OSX if is a .NET Library for .NET Framework

Tags: c#, .net, gembox-spreadsheet

I'm using .NET CORE cause i have a Mac, and i NEED use the GemBox.Spreadsheet, but is only available for .NET Framework. Is it possible to do something in order to use it with .NET CORE?

dotnet --version:

```
.NET Command Line Tools (1.0.0-beta-001598)

Product Information:
 Version:     1.0.0-beta-001598
 Commit Sha:  7582649f88

Runtime Environment:
 OS Name:     Mac OS X
 OS Version:  10.11
 OS Platform: Darwin
 Runtime Id:  osx.10.11-x64
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Good news guys! GemBox contacted me and said that they finally support .NET Standard 2.0. It means everything will work on .NET Core 2.0 and higher versions.

The release page - https://www.gemboxsoftware.com/news/gembox-spreadsheet-4-3-released

Also, I did not check it but some guys over the internet complain that export to PDF does not work on .NET Core ([Save XLSX file as PDF .NET Core (GemBox)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49517262/save-xlsx-file-as-pdf-net-core-gembox0)).

Anyway, that is a big deal. I love this library!

Comment: Previously GemBox.Spreadsheet for .NET Core supported saving to PDF only on Windows. But now, it has cross-platform support so it can be used on Linux and macOS as well. The release page: https://www.gemboxsoftware.com/news/support-for-pdf-on-linux-macos

Answer (score 0):

No, there is currently (4/7/2016) nothing you can do to get things built in .Net working with .Net Core.

Things that support .Net Core have to be compiled against it (check github tickets for the fun OSS projects like Dapper, NLog, etc are having getting ready for .Net Core).

Answer (score 0):

Some time ago (about a year maybe) I asked them directly about .net core support. They respond that they do not have plans to port the library to .net core because they have some dependencies (native I guess).
But anyway, now I see a vote block with platforms people use on their official site.
https://www.gemboxsoftware.com/spreadsheet/overview
Vote for .net core, maybe they change their minds and invest their time to porting the library to .net core.
Buy the way, the GemBox.Spreadsheet is an example of excellent library. It is fast, it is easy to use, it is feature reach. I definitely love it. and will be glad to use it in .net core project(s).