# Save XLSX file as PDF .NET Core (GemBox)

Tags: c#, .net, pdf, asp.net-core, gembox-spreadsheet

GemBox just released .NET Core version of their spreadsheet reading and writing software. I can successfully build and export spreadsheets as expected. However, when saving as PDF, I get the error:

`'SaveOptions.PdfDefault' is obsolete: 'PDF saving is not supported in .NET Standard.'`

In older versions, this was not an issue. In the .NET Standard/Core version, the function still exists, but gives this message. Is this just not possible with .NET Core, or has GemBox just not released the functionality?

Comment: Shouldn't you address this to the vendors support rather than here in SO? SO is about Programming related issues and problems, not about product features

Comment: I was trying to find out first if it was a GemBox product feature or part of .NET Standard because I've noticed other spreadsheet libraries for .NET Core also don't support exporting to PDF.

Comment: This feature is currently not available in .NET Standard version, it is only available in .NET Framework version.

Note that there are plans for implementing a rendering engine in .NET Standard version (the engine is used for saving an output file to PDF, XPS and image file formats), but I don't believe this will be available in a current year.  
For later I cannot say at the moment.

Comment: Thank you, Mario.

Answer (score 0):

The latest versions of GemBox.Spreadsheet have cross-platform support for saving to PDF, so from now on you can use `SaveOptions.PdfDefault` with **GemBox.Spreadsheet for .NET Standard 2.0**, see [Linux / macOS example](https://www.gemboxsoftware.com/spreadsheet/examples/create-excel-pdf-on-linux-net-core/5701).

Additionally, there is also a version of **GemBox.Spreadsheet for .NET Core 3.0** which supports saving to PDF as well, see [ASP.NET Core example](https://www.gemboxsoftware.com/spreadsheet/examples/asp-net-core-create-excel-xlsx-pdf/5601).